# Using a.vim for C++

Tags: c++, vim, editor, plugins

is there a way to use the a.vim plugin to switch between .h, .cxx *and* .txx files? Alternatively, can you provide another solution? The idea is to automagically switch from `.h -> .txx -> .cxx` at the press of a key.

**A Big Thanks** to both of you!

Comment: As an aside, what are .txx files?

Comment: I don't find them very useful, but in the project I work on, they are used to store templated code that is included in the .h file, in order to avoid polluting the .h file with actual code.

Comment: I'm missing the ability to switch from `.h` to `.hpp` to `.cpp` too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the lines in a.vim that contain `AddAlternateExtensionMapping`.  The first argument is the extension of the current file, the second is a list of extensions of the file you'd like to switch to with `:A`.  They are listed in **order of preference**.  In your case, you'd have to set it up so that it would go in a cycle.

```
call <SID>AddAlternateExtensionMapping('h', 'txx,cxx')
call <SID>AddAlternateExtensionMapping('txx', 'cxx,h')
call <SID>AddAlternateExtensionMapping('cxx', 'h,txx')
```

So now you go from .h to .txx if it exists or .cxx if it doesn't.

Comment: Very useful also to add the option to switch between .hh -> .cc ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, with the latest versions of *alternate*, there is an option that tells the preferred extensions to use. Did you have a look in the doc/first comment lines of the plugin?

Comment: I had a quick look, but it seems to always alternate between two types of files, not cycle through more.

Comment: No, as I understand it, it's about the next file to open. cpp -> h/hpp/... ; h -> c/cpp/... However, the first opened file found will be used. That's to say, you may have to open all your file before you see any cycle.

Answer (score 0):

A worthy alternative to *a.vim* is *altr*.

> [***altr***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4202) – Switch to the missing file without interaction

By default this plugin lets you switch between "alternate" Vim script files, C, C++, and Objective-C files, and ASP.NET files, but you can easily add your own alternates too.

After installation, set up the mappings that you prefer,

- either the *a.vim* way, using an Ex command

  ```
  command! A call altr#forward()
  ```
- or using mappings

  ```
  nmap <Leader>a <Plug>(altr-forward)
  nmap <Leader>A <Plug>(altr-back)
  ```