# Quickly switching between a file and a test file in vim

Tags: vim

Suppose I'm editing

```
src/a/b/c/d.c
```

and I expect a test file for this file to be in

```
test/a/b/c/d.c.c
```

how can I alternate between files following this pattern quickly?

Comment: Similar post: [In Vim how to switch quickly between .h and .cpp files with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17170902/438329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.vim and my [alternate-lite](https://github.com/LucHermitte/alternate-lite/) fork support a *searchpath* option where you could specify how we can (quickly) switch between directories. 
They're more tuned to jump between a header file and a definition file, but it should be possible to add test files as well -- I don't know how it'd behave with `.c.c` VS `.c` actually.

Given the pattern you've given us, the vanilla (non scalable) approach would be something like (untested):

```
function! s:alt_name(name) abort
    if a:name =~ '\.c\.c$'
        return substitute(a:name, '\v<test>/(.*)\.c', 'src/\1', '')
    elseif a:name =~ '\.c$'
        return substitute(a:name, '\v<src>/(.*\.c)', 'test/\1.c', '')
    else
        return a:name
    endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 Switch :exe ':e '.s:alt_name(expand('%'))
```

Of course, if you need to jump to a window where the buffer is already opened, or split, or... well. That's why there are plugins.

Comment: Fixing the numerous typos/errors in the code left as an exercise to the reader? :D I can accept this. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. I knew I was bound to have errors, but not that ones ^^'.
You're welcome