# How to triger clnagd.switchSourceHeader using built-in nvim lsp

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, coc.nvim, nvim-lspconfig

I used to do it with Coc.nvim

```
:CocCommand clangd.switchSourceHeader
```

But now I have moved to built-in nvim lsp and haven't any idea how to the same.

I found this solution for coc, but still dont how to do this for nvim lsp.

```
execute 'edit' CocRequest('clangd', 'textDocument/switchSourceHeader', {'uri': 'file://'.expand("%:p")})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the built-in LSP client, I recommend using the [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) plugin for configuring the servers.  For clangd, it creates a command `:ClangdSwitchSourceHeader` (see [documentation](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#clangd)).