# How to simplify file path containing ".." when opening file

Tags: vim

I have some `.h` files in `inc` folder and their corresponding `.cpp` files in `lib` folder.

```
D:\gitroot\Project\inc\A.h
D:\gitroot\Project\inc\B.h
D:\gitroot\Project\lib\A.cpp
D:\gitroot\Project\lib\B.cpp
```

I want to quickly open the corresponding `.cpp` file when working on the `.h` file, and vice-versa, so I put below maps in vimrc.

```
map \tdc :tabnew %:h/../lib/%:t:r.cpp<CR>
map \tdh :tabnew %:h/../inc/%:t:r.h<CR>
```

The problem is, when I use this to open the corresponding file, the file name of the tab is `Project\inc\..\lib\A.cpp` instead of `Project\lib\A.cpp`. How to simplify the file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:h` multiple times to remove both the file name and the containing subdirectory from the path.

```
map \tdc :tabnew %:h:h/lib/%:t:r.cpp<CR>
map \tdh :tabnew %:h:h/inc/%:t:r.h<CR>
```

(An example of this usage can be found in the documentation; see `:help filename-modifiers`.)

Comment: Thank you it works! Not sure if I should open new questions but I have some additional questions on it: (1). this solution solves the problem by not introducing the `..` in the first place, but what if there's already `..` in the path? e.g. if the currently opened file already has `..` in the path, the new file will also have `..`. (2) . If I opened `A.cpp` by `Project\inc\..\lib\A.cpp`, no matter how I close/open it again by `Project\lib\A.cpp`, it's always showing the same path with `..` until I reopen vim.

Comment: Definitely open a new question, but you should ask at vim.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Vim provides the `path` option which contains a list of paths where files are looked up in. Quoting from [`:help 'path'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27path%27):

> This is a list of directories which will be searched when using the
> gf, [f, ]f, ^Wf, :find, :sfind, :tabfind and other commands

Obviously, you want to open a new tab, so let's read [`:help :tabfind`](https://vimhelp.org/tabpage.txt.html#%3Atabfind) and confirm this is the command you were looking for.

Now you only need to add your `lib` and `inc` directories to `path` - let's prepend them with `^=` so your files are found first - and rewrite your mappings in terms of `:tabfind`:

```
set path^=D:\\gitroot\\Project
" or
set path^=../inc
set path^=../lib
" or why not just
set path^=../*

nnoremap <Leader>tdh <Cmd>tabfind %:t:r.h<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>tdc <Cmd>tabfind %:t:r.cpp<CR>
```

I took the liberty of adding some more improvements:

- limiting the scope from `:map` to `:nnoremap` which should be the default unless you need anything else. See [`:help map-modes`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-modes) for the subtle differences.
- using `<Leader>` which defaults to `\`. I assumed this was the intention of the mapping. If you want to use a literal backslash regardless of `mapleader`, ignore this item. Read [`:help mapleader`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapleader) for more information.
- using `<Cmd>` mappings which work without mode switching (not that there was any in this example). But it's good practice nevertheless. See [`:help <Cmd>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3CCmd%3E)

---

You might also find some of the answers in [In Vim how to switch quickly between .h and .cpp files with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170902/in-vim-how-to-switch-quickly-between-h-and-cpp-files-with-the-same-name) useful. I always found it nice to have *one* mapping to toggle between implementation and header files.